# Derive new item price based on discount applied to total

Tags: statistics, finance

I work for a business selling lists of assets that are assigned an expected sale price. Customers can bid on a list and make a total offer for the assets on the list.

For example, let's say that a list is comprised of 5 assets with the following expected sale prices:

25, 26, 27, 28, 29

The company would try to sell the list based on the sum of the expected sale prices (135). However, let's assume that a customer successfully offers a total of 100 for the list - ***I need to calculate the final sale price of each asset based on the percentage discount applied to the sum of expected sale prices*** so that the sum of final sale prices equals the discounted order total.

Many thanks to anyone who can help :)

Comment: You just need to multiply the expected price of each asset by $\frac{100}{135}$  In most cases, it won't work out exactly, there will be small rounding errors, so that the sum of the discounted prices will not be exactly equal to the amount received.  This will just be a matter of a few pennies.

Comment: It was my pleasure.